# Opening a file automatically on boot on Raspberry Pi3 b?

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian, services

I want to have a text file I created on LibreOffice Writer and saved in documents open automatically when I boot my raspberry pi. I know there is this https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md but it does not work for me. Does anyone know how to do it?

The following is in the service i created and i followed the steps in the link

```
[Unit] Description=test  
After=network.target 

[Service]  
ExecStart=/usr/bin/libreoffice-u testing.odt   
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Documents  
StandardOutput=inherit  
StandardError=inherit   
Restart=always  
User=pi  

[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Why does systemd not work for you?

Comment: The text file is not opening up upon boot

Comment: I mean how have you tried to implement it using systemd?

Comment: Like this and following the steps in the link [Unit]
Description=test
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/libreoffice-u testing.odt
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Documents
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: Please add that information in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: Not a good idea to use systemd, it's for  system service(which usually don't have or need UI), not normal GUI process. your need can be implemented by auto login into a Desktop session (implemented by Display Manager) and XDG autostart.

Comment: Boot into a desktop that end-user can use is much for complex than systemd system level services.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to start LibreOffice, you can move the application startup to XDG and auto start after a desktop environment has started

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Name=File 
Type=Application
Exec=libreoffice --writer /full/path/to/odt 
Terminal=false
```

Source: https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-autorun-application-at-the-start-up-in-linux#desktop_Files

Answer (score -1):

Running libreoffice automatically on boot requires that a graphical session should currently exist.

The desktop environment is loaded in `graphical.target`, which is after `multi-user.target`.
You also need to supply the proper environment variables for the session. Change the service configuration to the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=test

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/libreoffice --writer /full/path/to/testing.odt
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Documents
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
User=pi
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority"

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

**Note:** You also need to specify the **FULL** path to testing.odt.

After that reload the daemon configurations and enable it:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable <my_service>
```

And it should work.

Comment: It will not start any Display Server, so libreoffice will not run. Services that needs GUI needs to start Xorg like sddm or being a DRM master program.

Comment: It did not work.  @神秘德里克, Could you explain more about what I have to do?